# Can I run individual Granger Causality tests after doing Dumitrescu & Hurlins panel tests?

Tags: panel-data, stata, granger-causality

As a non-statistician, I want to run the Granger causality approach proposed by [Hurlin and Dumitrescu](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeeecmode/v_3a29_3ay_3a2012_3ai_3a4_3ap_3a1450-1460.htm). On page 3 the authors note three tests: Homogenous Non-Causality (HNC), Homogenous Causality (HC), HEterogenous Causality (HEC), HEterogenous Non-Causality (HENC).

My panel data consists of ~150 countries with several annual count data for 20 years. I have run `xtunitroot` to test for stationarity and transformed my variables accordingly (natlog & first difference).

I use `xtgcause` in Stata as it's described as the implementation of Dumitrescu & Hurlin.
However, which hypothesis test from page 3 am I actually testing here?

Again, using `xtgcause` for several combinations of these count data and one of the outputs is the following:

```
Dumitrescu & Hurlin (2012) Granger non-causality test results:
--------------------------------------------------------------
Optimal number of lags (BIC): 1 (lags tested: 1 to 4).
W-bar =          2.2011
Z-bar =         10.2973   (p-value = 0.0000)
Z-bar tilde =    7.1004   (p-value = 0.0000)
--------------------------------------------------------------
H0: X does not Granger-cause Y.
H1: X does Granger-cause Y for at least one panelvar (ID).
```

This lets me assume there is a possibility of a relationship between these two exemplified variables and I can proceed to identify these countries (?). Therefore, can I now run/ loop the standard `vargranger` over all countries? [`vargranger`](https://www.stata.com/manuals/tsvargranger.pdf) is Statas standard pairwise Granger Test.

In short, I want to:

1. identify/find out which hypothesis I am actually testing using `xtgcause`
2. find a combination of variables using `xtgcause` that rejects the null hypothesis
3. use `vargranger` on these combinations to identify countries where the relationship is significant

Is this procedure statistically feasible/ correct?

I'm sorry this is a combination of coding and statistical question!